# Express Route not firing when called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route defined in my express app, and I have it inside a router that is imported into my app in the main file.

I have my router installed like this in `index.js`

```
const Routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/address', Routes.AddressRoutes);
```

in the routes folder, I have the address router exposed like this:

```
//./routes/index.js
const AddressRoutes = require('./address');
module.exports = Routes = {
    AddressRoutes,
};

// ./routes/address.js
const router = require('express').Router();
const {Address} = require('./routeActions');
module.exports = () => {
    router.post('/', Address.add);
    return router;
};

// ./routes/routeActions/index.js
const Address = require('./user');

module.exports =  {
  Address,
};

// ./routes/routeActions/address.js
module.exports = Address = {
    add: (req,res) => {....}
};
```

The issue is that I have a breakpoint in VS code inside the `add()` function, but the only thing that get's hit is the definition of the route, and not the actual handler. Am I making the modules too complicated? How can I get the handler to be called so I can debug it?

Comment: Do you have index.js inside the routes folder?

Comment: you've exports as `module.exports = () => ... ` which return router object, but I don't see it called

Comment: There is an `index.js` at the root of the project, where the `app.use` statement is, an `index.js` inside `./routes` wrapping all route definition files into a module, and an `index.js` inside `./routes/routeActions/` that wraps the handlers into a module.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar thanks for this. I may be forgetting that..... not calling it to instantiate the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options to fix.

When adding the route definitions, run the function that is exported.

`const Address = require('./address')();`

Or when exporting the route definitions, simply export the router from the file.

`module.exports = router;` not `module.exports = () => {routeHandlers.... return router}`